# Windows Azure Mobile Services Time(mssql) JSON serialization error

Tags: json, azure, windows-runtime, azure-mobile-services

I'm having a problem with the time data type in SQL. I'm using a TimespanConverter as described here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/08/30/supporting-arbitrary-types-in-azure-mobile-services-managed-client-simple-types.aspx which works fine inserting data but when retrieving it returns a DateTime in the universal format (without the time in the correct place). For example a time of '14:45:00' will return '0013-12-31T00:00:00.000Z' and for earlier times such at '09:00:00' null is returned.

Is anyone else facing the same issue?

Thanks in advance!

(Also posted here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/azuremobile/thread/5110ed4b-7912-49d9-9e6c-9acd9277d52b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has since been confirmed as an issue with Microsoft's Node JS SQL driver:

> "I am able to reproduce the problem within node-sqlserver itself.  We will work on a fix. Thanks for bringing this to our attention."
>
> From http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/azuremobile/thread/5110ed4b-7912-49d9-9e6c-9acd9277d52b